# how to change value of all match property in nested objects in using state array reactjs / react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setstate

This is my json response

```
const [shopRecord, setShopRecord] = useState({
  shopSetting: {
    shop_name: '',
    shop_address: '',
    shop_tel: '',
    shop_email: '',
  },
  menuCourse: [
    {
      name: 'Fish',
      items: [
        {
          id: '1',
          name: 'Fish & Chips Deal',
          is_selected: 1,
          modifiers: [
            {
              title: 'Select one option',
              options: [
                {
                  name: 'Medium Cod',
                  stockno: '102',
                  is_selected: 1,
                  price: 0,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Medium Haddock',
                  stockno: '103',
                  is_selected: 0,
                  price: 0,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              title: 'Select one option',
              options: [
                {
                  name: 'Medium Chips',
                  stockno: '106',
                  is_selected: 1,
                  price: 0,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Large Chips',
                  stockno: '107',
                  is_selected: 0,
                  price: 60,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              title: 'Select one option',
              options: [
                {
                  name: 'Salt',
                  stockno: '108',
                  is_selected: 1,
                  price: 0,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              title: 'Select one option',
              options: [
                {
                  name: 'Mushy Peas',
                  stockno: '112',
                  is_selected: 0,
                  price: 0,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Curry Sauce',
                  stockno: '114',
                  is_selected: 1,
                  price: 0,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              title: 'Select an option',
              options: [
                {
                  name: 'Rubicon Guava',
                  stockno: '119',
                  is_selected: 0,
                  price: 100,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Vimto',
                  stockno: '121',
                  is_selected: 1,
                  price: 100,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
          price: 1080,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

I'm trying to change all the match property `"is_selected": 1` to `"is_selected": 0`

I have a Flatlist component which display a list of menu using **shopRecord**.
It have a property **menuCourse** which is an array of objects and each object has a property **items** which is also an array of objects and it have a property of **modifiers** which is also an array contain another property **options** which is also an array of objects.

Once user click any **options** I changed updated the **is_selected** property to **1**. which is working fine so far, Once user click add to cart button I just pass the whole **items** object to my store and I have a function in place which remove the unselected items from that object.

What I want to do is to change all the **is_selected** property back to **0**.

How can I access multiple levels of nested objects and not mutate the state?

I am doing this but the console of the **shopRecord** shows the value is not changed.

```
setShopRecord(prevState => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    menuCourse: prevState.menuCourse.map(menuObj =>
      menuObj.items.length > 0
        ? {
            ...menuObj,
            items: menuObj.items.map(itemObj =>
              itemObj.modifiers > 0
                ? {
                    ...itemObj,
                    is_selected: 0,
                    modifiers: itemObj.modifiers.map(modifierObj =>
                      modifierObj.options > 0
                        ? {
                            ...modifierObj,
                            options: modifierObj.options.map(optionObj =>
                              optionObj.is_selected == 1
                                ? {...optionObj, is_selected: 0}
                                : optionObj,
                            ),
                          }
                        : modifierObj,
                    ),
                  }
                : {...itemObj, is_selected: 0},
            ),
          }
        : menuObj,
    ),
  };
});
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: ```itemObj.modifiers > 0```missing length and ```modifierObj.options```missing length

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBahl for pointing out the typo. But this typo didn't help me achieving. What I'm looking for. :(

Answer (score 0):

As stated by `@michael Bahl` `.length` was missing and rest of the code is correct. The reason you don't see updated value in the console is because of the concept of updater in react. React does not change the value of the state immediately, all state setters go through an updater which updates the value of the state. This is done for efficiency. Instead of updating individual states, react updates multiple states together.

Lets understand this by example,

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
console.log(myState);//false
setMyState(prevVal => {
   console.log(prevVal);//false
   const updatedVal = !prevVal;
   console.log(updatedVal);//true;
   return updatedVal;
);
console.log(myState);//false
```

In above code, you can see the behavior of state updater.

So for your code you can check if the value is updating or not using below code.

```
setShopRecord(prevState => {
            const result = {
                ...prevState,
                menuCourse: prevState.menuCourse.map(menuObj =>
                    menuObj.items.length > 0
                        ? {
                            ...menuObj,
                            items: menuObj.items.map(itemObj =>
                                itemObj.modifiers.length > 0
                                    ? {
                                        ...itemObj,
                                        is_selected: 0,
                                        modifiers: itemObj.modifiers.map(modifierObj =>
                                            modifierObj.options.length > 0
                                                ? {
                                                    ...modifierObj,
                                                    options: modifierObj.options.map(optionObj =>
                                                        optionObj.is_selected == 1
                                                            ? { ...optionObj, is_selected: 0 }
                                                            : optionObj,
                                                    ),
                                                }
                                                : modifierObj,
                                        ),
                                    }
                                    : { ...itemObj, is_selected: 0 },
                            ),
                        }
                        : menuObj,
                ),
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));//here you will see updated value
            return result;
});
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you @Vipul Bhoir for the explanation. I'll have a look.